# Why Am I Not able to Write Data To Firebase using Js via Html?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just tried To write a very basic data to my firebase database but it isn't working. Here's is the code that i've used

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
function writeUserData() {
          firebase.database().ref('users').set({ uId: document.getElementById('fname').value,
            refercode:document.getElementById('lname').value})
            </script>
    <form name="myForm">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">text1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your PlayStore Email.." required></input>
         <div class="col-25">
           <label for="lname">text2</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-75">
           <input type="text" id="lname" name="codename" placeholder="Your PlayStore Email.." required></input>
      </div> <button onclick="writeUserData()" class="button">Request Withdrawal</button></form>
```

But this isn't writing any data on to my database. It returns an error in console, "writeUserData" is not defined.How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since your script block is typed as a `module`, the internals of it are not available globally.

One way to make your `writeUserData` available to the button click handler is to add it to the `window` object as shown here: [JS modules - ReferenceError: <function> is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268248/js-modules-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined)

But a better solution is to not depend on an inline `onclick` handler, and instead attach the handler in the script module itself with `addEventListener` like:

```
<script type="module">
  ...
  function writeUserData() {
    firebase.database().ref('users').set({ uId: 
      document.getElementById('fname').value,
      refercode:document.getElementById('lname').value
    })
  }

  // 
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', writeUserData)
</script>
```